# How to show icon on specific area after click on button?

Tags: flutter

**My Goal:** 
When user click on RaisedButton i would like to show a icon.

**My problem:** 
I don't know how to show icon on specific area

**My  code:** 
This code generate some responses buttons (Europe, Asia, Africa, ..)

```
for (var i = 0; i < NumberChoice; i++)
RaisedButton(
  color: _colorButton,
  child: new Text(
    _choice[i],
    style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white),
  ),
  onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
      if (_choice[i] == answer) {
        print("--------------- Corect ----------------");
        //--HERE  HOW TO SHOW ICON IF USER CLICK ON BUTTON--
        Icon(
          Icons.check,
          color: Colors.green,
          size: 24.0,
        );
        scoreResult = 1;
      } else {
        print("--------------- False ------------------------");
        //--HERE  HOW TO SHOW ICON IF USER CLICK ON BUTTON--
        Icon(
          Icons.close,
          color: Colors.red,
          size: 24.0,
        );
        scoreResult = 0;
      }
    });
  },
)
```

**Example** 
If user click on "Europe" , then "Icons.check" displayed where i added "Button here" . 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand

1. create a string like this : -

   ```
   String choice;
   ```
2. change it to true whenever u click on raised button

   ```
   choice == answer              
        ? // show widget if correct
        : SizedBox()
   ```

Comment: I added some explanations in my subjet. My goal is to "add" button if the user answers correctly.